# Calculate 'const char *' string hash at compile-time

Tags: c++, constexpr, consteval

I have a function that calculates the hash of a string literal:

```
inline consteval uint64_t HashLiteral(const char* key)
{
   // body not important here...
   return 0;
}
```

In another function I need both the literal string, and its hash which I want to have calculated at compile-time:

```
void function(const char* s)
{
   worker(s, HashLiteral(s));
}
```

It seems however be impossible to make such a call like `function("string")` and have the hash calculated in its body at compile-time. The best I came up for now is using a macro, and redefine the function:

```
#define MakeHashParms(s)   s,HashLiteral(s)
void function(const char* s, const uint64_t hash)
{
   worker(s, hash);
}
function(MakeHashParms("string"));
```

Is a more straightforward solution possible?

Comment: I've used Python as a pre-preprocessor in a C++ program before, so that Python could generate code at compile time.  I'd generate things like lookup tables.  Could be used to precalculate the hashes very easily.  This was before we had as much fancy C++ template compile time meta-programming.

Comment: @Eljay: sounds fancy, but not something I'd like to do. In the end, the function call `function("string");` should be as simple and C++ alike as possible, so my hope is that some wizzard knows how to use the newest C++ thingies to accomplish that. My macro solution works, but already feels a bit 'iffy'.

Comment: Maybe create a "hashed string" struct with a constexpr constructor, and pass that instead? You could also define a  [user defined literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) for it.

Comment: @Brian61354270: I'm not certain if the struct thing will work. What I understood is that it's difficult to have constexpr in all the right places to guarantee compile-time evaluation. I'll look into the string literals also, no idea how that works :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify `function` to accept a "hashed string" structure which can be [implicitly constructed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) from a `const char*`. If you make the conversion constructor [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval), you can guarantee that the hash is always computed at compile time.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

inline consteval std::uint64_t HashLiteral(const char*)
{
   // body not important here...
   return 0;
}

struct HashedString {
    const char* str;
    std::uint64_t hash;

    consteval HashedString(const char* s)
        : str{s}, hash{HashLiteral(s)} {}
};

void worker(const char*, std::uint64_t) {};

void function(HashedString s)
{
    worker(s.str, s.hash);
}

int main() 
{
    function("string");  // OK: hash computed at compile time

    const char* x = "runtime string";
    // function(x);      // error: x is not constant expression
}
```

[Try it online on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/d5n6EGv39)

Comment: This seems to work great! No call to HashLiteral() to be seen in the assembly...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the compiler has to generate runtime version of `function()` and there is no runtime version of `HashLiteral()` to do that.

The hash **has to** be calculated external to the `function()`, but you don't have to use macros for that. You can either use a struct as Brian suggested in his answer, or just make your `HashLiteral()` function bundle the original string with the hash.

For extra brevity (thanks Brian) and readability you could do this:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>

consteval auto HashLiteral(const char* s)
{
    std::uint64_t hash = 0;
    // body not important here...
    return std::make_tuple(s, hash);
}

void worker(const char*, std::uint64_t)
{
    // do work
}

void function(const auto& sh)
{
    const auto& [s, hash] = sh;
    worker(s, hash);
}

consteval auto operator""_hashed(const char* s, std::size_t) { return HashLiteral(s); }

int main()
{
    function("string"_hashed);
}
```

Ref: https://godbolt.org/z/ssqoz91qs

Comment: For extra brevity, you could replace the call to `HashLiteral` with a [user-defined literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) like `"string"_hashed`. Example on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/3dKdKToM6